# Error while pushing code to staging branch from CI/CD job

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I have a question. My branch name is issue_123 and I am pushing code to this branch. Now this is my CI/CD file.

```
stages:
  - merge
  - test
  - deploy
  
merge_to_staging:
  stage: merge
  script:
    - echo "Merging branch into staging..."
    - git checkout staging
    - git merge origin/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    - echo "before pushing to staging"
    - git push origin staging
    - echo "after pushing to staging"
  except:
    - master
    - staging

test_job:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "preparing testing server"
    - echo "Running tests......."
    # - bundle install
    # - bundle exec rails db:create RAILS_ENV=test
    # - bundle exec rails db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
    # - rails test
  only: 
    - staging

deploy_to_staging:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - staging
  before_script:
    # - rake task:run -e production
  script:
    - echo "preparing staging server"
    - echo "Deploying to staging server.............."
    # - git pull origin staging
  after_script:
    # - rails db:migrate -e production
    # - bundle install -e production

deploy_to_live:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  before_script:
    # - rake task:run -e production
  script:
    - echo "preparing production environment"
    - echo "Deploying to Live servers..."
    # - git pull origin master
  after_script:
    # - rails db:migrate -e production
    # - bundle install -e production
    - echo "After deploy is running"
```

It merges the changes but not pushes to staging branch remotely. Now when I push branch to staging branch manually , it does happen. Following is the code of job logs

> Running with gitlab-runner 15.11.0 (436955cb)   on implementation
> 2bEomyvNr, system ID: s_ee2745355f72 Preparing the "shell" executor
> 00:00 Using Shell (bash) executor... Preparing environment 00:00
> Running on ansthinkpad... Getting source from Git repository 00:03
> Fetching changes with git depth set to 20... Reinitialized existing
> Git repository in
> /home/gitlab-runner/builds/2bEomyvNr/0/ansm6927/ci-cd-implementation/.git/
> Checking out fd8d1acf as detached HEAD (ref is issue_123)... Skipping
> Git submodules setup Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
> 00:01 $ echo "Merging branch into staging..." Merging branch into
> staging... $ git checkout staging Previous HEAD position was fd8d1ac
> Update .gitlab-ci.yml file Switched to branch 'staging' Your branch
> and 'origin/staging' have diverged, and have 6 and 1 different commits
> each, respectively.   (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into
> yours) $ git merge origin/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME Updating
> d0d3a50..fd8d1ac Fast-forward  .gitlab-ci.yml | 4 +++-  1 file
> changed, 3 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-) $ echo "before pushing to
> staging" before pushing to staging $ git push origin staging remote:
> You are not allowed to upload code. fatal: unable to access
> 'https://gitlab.com/ansm6927/ci-cd-implementation.git/': The requested
> URL returned error: 403 Cleaning up project directory and file based
> variables 00:00 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

Comment: Does your organisation enforce SSH Key based access to the repositories ?

Comment: Please add the command-line that produced the log to the question. Which user is executing the command? Which user is the shell executor run under?